# Student's Book vs. Student Book

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

Today my daughter and I were listening to directions in a children's course where the speaker said something like "[in the] student book"; I was not really sure about "in the" part. My daughter said the meaning of which "this is wrong! He should have said: ... the student's book". I didn't know what to say but this is okay.

I heard both but the problem is I don't know if there's any rule or it's arbitrary! This question was in mind long time ago but it's now or never.

By the way, what I am sure about is that the student's book has this phrase on the front cover "Student Book". So it's not plural just in case you might say what the speaker actually says is "in the students' book". It's a possibility but I really doubt it. It's very unlikely especially when I hear both "... the student book" and "... the student's book"

Could anyone enlighten me please?

**Update:**

Interested people could read this article: [Happy "Veterans' Day," "Veteran's Day," or "Veterans Day"? Possessives vs. Attributive Nouns](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/111108possattrib.htm)

Or this: [Possessive Forms](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/possessives.htm)

Comment: FYI, one of my grammar books is *Students' English Grammar* by Jake Allsop. :-)

Comment: I think in "Student Book" student is an adjective and I think its better to say "Student Book" if we are speaking generally about books that are designed for students.

Comment: Possessive s vs attributive adjectives is an interesting point to think about.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's called [attributive nouns](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Attributive-Noun.htm) not attributive adjectives

Comment: cf. the abridged version of LGSWE is called the Longman **Student** Grammar of Spoken and Written English.

Comment: *The student's book* is a book which belongs to the student. *The student book* may be either a book about/intended for the specific student or a book about/intended for students generally.

Comment: Yes. The difference comes from the definition of each term, the **possessive** case and **attributive** noun. In "The student's book", what's pivotal is the student i.e. the book belongs to the student or the student 'has' the book. In "The student book", the book is pivotal, and the student is a property/attribute of the book. I imagine If one can think of possible scenarios to using these idiomatic phrases it proves they understand it well. **The reader's digest-The reader digest-The writer's guide-The writer guide.

Comment: @learner I believe that you've gathered enough information to write a good answer, and it would be useful to everyone if you do so. I believe that it's perfectly fine to answer our own questions after doing our research (and/or having good comments).

Comment: Thanks for the positive comment DT, but I think I'm not confident enough, and if I were I wouldn't be able to because I'm busy with my pile of questions! I may return the favor later to SE when I'm ready.

Answer (score 3):

"student's book"  , a book that  belongs to a student.

"student book" ,a book that is written for students and that group of

students can use it.